# GDI+ Drawing Rectangle Is Slow

Tags: c#, performance, gdi+

I've developed a Windows Forms Application to draw a rectangular region relevant to the user's mouse position as he or she clicks, holds and drags the mouse.

The class is very simple and is as followed:

```
public partial class MainForm : LayeredForm
{
    private bool drawing = false;
    private Point startLocation = Point.Empty;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;
        Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        TopMost = true;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private void MainForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        drawing = true;
        startLocation = e.Location;
    }

    private void MainForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawing)
            Invalidate();
    }

    private void MainForm_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        drawing = false;
    }

    private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(Math.Min(startLocation.X, Cursor.Position.X), Math.Min(startLocation.Y, Cursor.Position.Y),
            Math.Abs(startLocation.X - Cursor.Position.X), Math.Abs(startLocation.Y - Cursor.Position.Y));

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, r);
    }
}


public class LayeredForm : Form
{
    public new event PaintEventHandler Paint;

    public LayeredForm()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (DesignMode) return base.CreateParams;
            CreateParams cParams = base.CreateParams;
            cParams.ExStyle = cParams.ExStyle | 0x80000;
            return cParams;
        }
    }

    private void PaintNative(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr hdcDestination = Win32.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr hdcSource = Win32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDestination);
        IntPtr hdcBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr previousBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            hdcBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));
            previousBitmap = Win32.SelectObject(hdcSource, hdcBitmap);

            Win32.SIZE size = new Win32.SIZE(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            Win32.POINT source = new Win32.POINT(0, 0);
            Win32.POINT destination = new Win32.POINT(Left, Top);
            Win32.BLENDFUNCTION blendFunc = new Win32.BLENDFUNCTION()
            {
                BlendOp = Win32.AC_SRC_OVER,
                BlendFlags = 0,
                SourceConstantAlpha = 50,
                AlphaFormat = Win32.AC_SRC_ALPHA
            };

            Win32.UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, hdcDestination, ref destination, ref size, hdcSource, ref source, 0, ref blendFunc, 2);
        }
        finally
        {
            Win32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdcDestination);
            if (hdcBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32.SelectObject(hdcSource, previousBitmap);
                Win32.DeleteObject(hdcBitmap);
            }
            Win32.DeleteDC(hdcSource);
        }
    }

    public new void Invalidate()
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                if (Paint != null)
                    Paint(this, new PaintEventArgs(graphics, Rectangle.Empty));
            }
            PaintNative(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

On my computer and most others, everything runs fine. However, after concluding some testing on various machines I found that some computers where struggling to draw the rectangle (noticeably slow, and choppy). I think I have identified the issue however I am in need of validation and a resolution to this issue.

I believe that the problem lies with the fact that every time the mouse move event is raised, the entire form is drawn again, and again. On weak computers with large resolutions, this is very strenuous.

After conducting some research, I think that the solution is to only draw the part of the rectangle that's changed and not the entire form, although I'm clueless as to how to do this. I'd really appreciate any help that SO can offer, thanks in advance.

### Update

Complete code for Ken:

```
public sealed partial class RegionForm : LayeredWindow // : Form
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private bool mouseDown;
    private Point newPoint = Point.Empty;
    private Point oldPoint = Point.Empty;
    private Point startPoint = Point.Empty;

    public RegionForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;
        Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        TopMost = true;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    private void regionPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(regionPanel.ClientSize.Width,
                            regionPanel.ClientSize.Height,
                            PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        regionPanel.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, regionPanel.ClientRectangle);
        startPoint = e.Location;
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    private void regionPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = false;

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmap = null;
        }

        Rectangle region = new Rectangle(startPoint, new Size(oldPoint.X - startPoint.X + 1,
                                                              oldPoint.Y - startPoint.Y + 1));
        regionPanel.Invalidate(region, true);
    }

    private void regionPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            using (Graphics g = regionPanel.CreateGraphics())
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
                newPoint = e.Location;
                ClearRegion(g);
                oldPoint = newPoint;
                DrawRegion(g);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DrawRegion(Graphics g)
    {
        int x1 = startPoint.X;
        int y1 = startPoint.Y;
        int x2 = newPoint.X;
        int y2 = newPoint.Y;

        //block "negative" selection
        if (x1 > x2)
        {
            x2 = x1;
        }
        if (y1 > y2)
        {
            y2 = y1;
        }

        //Draw a red rectangle
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    }

    private void ClearRegion(Graphics g)
    {
        int x1 = startPoint.X;
        int y1 = startPoint.Y;
        int x2 = oldPoint.X;
        int y2 = oldPoint.Y;

        if (x1 > x2)
        {
            x2 = x1;
        }
        if (y1 > y2)
        {
            y2 = y1;
        }

        //check left line
        if (newPoint.Y < y2)
        {
            Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(x1, newPoint.Y, 1, oldPoint.Y - newPoint.Y);
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        //upper line
        if (newPoint.X < x2)
        {
            Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(newPoint.X, y1, oldPoint.X - newPoint.X, 1);
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        //right line
        if (newPoint.X != x2 || newPoint.Y < y2)
        {
            int h = 0;
            int y = 0;
            if (newPoint.X == x2)
            {
                y = newPoint.Y;
                h = oldPoint.Y - newPoint.Y + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                y = startPoint.Y;
                h = oldPoint.Y - startPoint.Y + 1;
            }

            Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(oldPoint.X, y, 1, h);
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        //bottom line
        if (newPoint.Y != y2 || newPoint.X < x2)
        {
            int w = 0;
            int x = 0;

            if (newPoint.Y == y2)
            {
                x = newPoint.X;
                w = oldPoint.X - newPoint.X + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                x = startPoint.X;
                w = oldPoint.X - x1 + 1;
            }

            Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(x, oldPoint.Y, w, 1);
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }

public class LayeredWindow : Form
{
    public new event PaintEventHandler Paint;

    public LayeredWindow()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (DesignMode) return base.CreateParams;
            CreateParams cParams = base.CreateParams;
            cParams.ExStyle = cParams.ExStyle | 0x80000;
            return cParams;
        }
    }

    private void PaintNative(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr hdcDestination = Win32.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr hdcSource = Win32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDestination);
        IntPtr hdcBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr previousBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            hdcBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));
            previousBitmap = Win32.SelectObject(hdcSource, hdcBitmap);

            Size size = new Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            Point source = new Point(0, 0);
            Point destination = new Point(Left, Top);
            Win32.BLENDFUNCTION blendFunc = new Win32.BLENDFUNCTION()
            {
                BlendOp = Win32.AC_SRC_OVER,
                BlendFlags = 0,
                SourceConstantAlpha = 50,
                AlphaFormat = Win32.AC_SRC_ALPHA
            };

            Win32.UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, hdcDestination, ref destination, ref size, hdcSource, ref source, 0, ref blendFunc, 2);
        }
        finally
        {
            Win32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdcDestination);
            if (hdcBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32.SelectObject(hdcSource, previousBitmap);
                Win32.DeleteObject(hdcBitmap);
            }
            Win32.DeleteDC(hdcSource);
        }
    }

    public new void Invalidate()
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                if (Paint != null)
                    Paint(this, new PaintEventArgs(graphics, Rectangle.Empty));
            }
            PaintNative(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class Win32
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UpdateLayeredWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcDst, ref Point pptDst, ref Size psize, IntPtr hdcSrc, ref Point pptSrc, uint crKey, [In] ref BLENDFUNCTION pblend, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int xDest, int yDest, int wDest, int hDest, IntPtr hdcSource, int xSrc, int ySrc, CopyPixelOperation rop);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rect);

    public const byte AC_SRC_OVER = 0;
    public const byte AC_SRC_ALPHA = 1;
    public const byte ULW_ALPHA = 2;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct BLENDFUNCTION
    {
        public byte BlendOp;
        public byte BlendFlags;
        public byte SourceConstantAlpha;
        public byte AlphaFormat;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

}
```

Solution Download: http://www.mediafire.com/?b9ql4pzh69u10n4

Answer (score 4):

You need to draw it from the `MouseMove` event. Invalidating the whole control will be slow on some computers/resolutions.

UPDATE:

This code will draw and clear the rectangle for selected region in a highly optimized way.

The routine draws a rectangle on `MouseMove`, but only clears fragments of the lines as needed. That is if the region is smaller than the previous size only the outer parts of the lines are cleared from the stored bitmap.

Due to this there is no need to enable double-buffering.

In order to get the buffered bitmap of the window in correct position as source copy we need to implement a small trick:

- Add a `Panel` (panFill in this example) to the form and set docking to fill.
- Add all controls / background image to the panel, not the form

Now we can copy the bitmap we need later from the `Panel` instead of the `Form`. The reason we need this is that using `this.DrawBitmap()` will draw borders and title-bar to the bitmap too and we don't want that. Using the `Panel` will eliminate this.

In the global scope of the form's class we set:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
bool inDrag = false;
Point regStart = Point.Empty;
Point regNew = Point.Empty;
Point regOld = Point.Empty;
```

On the Panel's MouseDown/Up event:

```
private void panFill_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Create a bitmap
    bmp = new Bitmap(panFill.ClientSize.Width, _
                     panFill.ClientSize.Height, _
                     Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

    panFill.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panFill.ClientRectangle);

    //store origo/start point and mark that we're active
    regStart = e.Location;
    inDrag = true;
}

private void panFill_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    inDrag = false;

    //we're done, clean up resources if any
    if (bmp != null) {
        bmp.Dispose();
        bmp = null; //use as marker for this check
    }

    //clean up by redrawing panel
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(regStart, _
                                new Size(regOld.X - regStart.X + 1, _
                                         regOld.Y - regStart.Y + 1));
    panFill.Invalidate(r, true);

}
```

In our `MouseMove` event we call clear and draw a new rectangle:

```
private void panFill_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (inDrag) {

        using (Graphics g = panFill.CreateGraphics) {
            g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;

            //we store new pos. here as it's used to calculate
            //delta for what we need to redraw
            regNew = e.Location;
            ClearRegion(g);

            regOld = regNew;
            DrawRegion(g);
            }
        }
}
```

The function to draw the rectangle is pretty straight forward:

```
private void DrawRegion(Graphics g)
{
    int x1 = regStart.X;
    int y1 = regStart.Y;
    int x2 = regNew.X;
    int y2 = regNew.Y;

    //block "negative" selection
    if (x1 > x2) {
        x2 = x1;
    }
    if (y1 > y2) {
        y2 = y1;
    }

    //Draw a red rectangle
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
}
```

The next method holds all the magic optimized to only draw what is needed. It achieve this by checking the two main lines from origo and if the length has shrunk. If so it calculate the delta for the old position and the new position and only redraws the "gap".

For the two other lines if do the same if the tangent position is the same, if not it redraws the whole line.

```
private void ClearRegion(Graphics g)
{
    int x1 = regStart.X;
    int y1 = regStart.Y;
    int x2 = regOld.X;
    int y2 = regOld.Y;

    if (x1 > x2) {
        x2 = x1;
    }
    if (y1 > y2) {
        y2 = y1;
    }

    //check left line
    if (regNew.Y < y2) {
        Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(x1, regNew.Y, 1, regOld.Y - regNew.Y);
        g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectds, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    //upper line
    if (regNew.X < x2) {
        Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(regNew.X, y1, regOld.X - regNew.X, 1);
        g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    //right line
    if (regNew.X != x2 || regNew.Y < y2) {
        int h = 0;
        int y = 0;
        if (regNew.X == x2) {
            y = regNew.Y;
            h = regOld.Y - regNew.Y + 1;
        } else {
            y = regStart.Y;
            h = regOld.Y - regStart.Y + 1;
        }

        Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(regOld.X, y, 1, h);
        g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    //bottom line
    if (regNew.Y != y2 || regNew.X < x2) {
        int w = 0;
        int x = 0;

        if (regNew.Y == y2) {
            x = regNew.X;
            w = regOld.X - regNew.X + 1;
        } else {
            x = regStart.X;
            w = regOld.X - x1 + 1;
        }

        Rectangle rectdst = new Rectangle(x, regOld.Y, w, 1);
        g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    }
}
```

This is the, I would say, the most you can get out of GDI+ on a form. Different approaches involved DirectX and more low-level stuff. By limiting what is redrawn based on need, the speed is optimal.

Also notice that the bitmap copy of the fill panel is PARG which is the fastest type as alpha is pre-multiplied. I am, although not necessary in this case, setting smoothing mode to none so the lines will keep themselves sharp without any aliasing leaking.

On a Windows XP 32-bit, 2 GB memory and Atom CPU this runs smooth as it gets.

Note: original code is written in VB and translated to C#. Some errors may occure - adjust as needed. Add handlers as needed.

The original VB code for those interested:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private bmp As Bitmap = Nothing
    Private inDrag As Boolean = False
    Private regStart As Point = Point.Empty
    Private regNew As Point = Point.Empty
    Private regOld As Point = Point.Empty

    Public Event RegionSelected(r As Rectangle)

    Private Sub panfill_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles panFill.MouseDown

        bmp = New Bitmap(panFill.ClientSize.Width, panFill.ClientSize.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
        panFill.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panFill.ClientRectangle)

        regStart = e.Location

        inDrag = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub panFill_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles panFill.MouseMove

        If inDrag Then
            Using g As Graphics = panFill.CreateGraphics

                g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None

                regNew = e.Location

                ClearRegion(g)

                regOld = regNew

                DrawRegion(g)

            End Using

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub panFill_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles panFill.MouseUp

        inDrag = False

        If bmp IsNot Nothing Then
            bmp.Dispose()
            bmp = Nothing
        End If

        Dim r As New Rectangle(regStart, New Size(regOld.X - regStart.X + 1, regOld.Y - regStart.Y + 1))
        panFill.Invalidate(r, True)

        RaiseEvent RegionSelected(r)

    End Sub
    Private Sub DrawRegion(g As Graphics)

        Dim x1, y1, x2, y2 As Integer
        x1 = regStart.X
        y1 = regStart.Y
        x2 = regNew.X
        y2 = regNew.Y

        If x1 > x2 Then
            x2 = x1
        End If
        If y1 > y2 Then
            y2 = y1
        End If

        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

    End Sub
    Private Sub ClearRegion(g As Graphics)

        Dim x1, y1, x2, y2 As Integer

        x1 = regStart.X
        y1 = regStart.Y
        x2 = regOld.X
        y2 = regOld.Y

        If x1 > x2 Then
            x2 = x1
        End If
        If y1 > y2 Then
            y2 = y1
        End If

        'left line
        If regNew.Y < y2 Then

            Dim rectdst As New Rectangle(x1, regNew.Y, 1, regOld.Y - regNew.Y)
            g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        End If

        'upper line
        If regNew.X < x2 Then

            Dim rectdst As New Rectangle(regNew.X, y1, regOld.X - regNew.X, 1)
            g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        End If

        'right line
        If regNew.X <> x2 OrElse regNew.Y < y2 Then

            Dim h, y As Integer
            If regNew.X = x2 Then
                y = regNew.Y
                h = regOld.Y - regNew.Y + 1
            Else
                y = regStart.Y
                h = regOld.Y - regStart.Y + 1
            End If

            Dim rectdst As New Rectangle(regOld.X, y, 1, h)
            g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        End If

        'bottom line
        If regNew.Y <> y2 OrElse regNew.X < x2 Then

            Dim w, x As Integer
            If regNew.Y = y2 Then
                x = regNew.X
                w = regOld.X - regNew.X + 1
            Else
                x = regStart.X
                w = regOld.X - x1 + 1
            End If

            Dim rectdst As New Rectangle(x, regOld.Y, w, 1)
            g.DrawImage(bmp, rectdst, rectdst, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is a very good approach. But saving the content to an image on MouseDown only works if the content is static - displaying no dynamic content in between.

Comment: You can get around that by copying the lines as bitmaps instead of the whole bitmap. Of course this need to happen on a "frame" basis, ie. update each time an invalidate/change occur. XOR'ed lines comes handy for this.

Comment: I tried this logic, you can try it yourself using my current example. It didn't improve the performance.

Comment: @Alex I updated answer with a complete example. This is highly optimized and should work smooth on most computers. If any errors due to VB->C# conversion, please adjust as needed.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Thanks man, I really appreciate your effort here. I tested this with a plain Windows Forms Application and it runs just fine but I can't get this working with my layered window. Notice my class inherits the LayeredWindow class. Do you know how I can get this working with the LayeredWindow and could you also explain the need for the Panel control some more because at the moment, I'm reluctant to use it.

Comment: @Alex That's strange. Could you show a little more code in OP how you setup the layered window? The Panel control is just to capture the window without borders and titlebar. By dropping in one and setting it's dock property to fill, it will cover the complete inner area of the form. When then using DrawToBitmap only the inner part of the window is captured. Problem is that the form won't capture the mouse-down/up etc. so we need to use the Panel's events to do this. Then just add other controls to the panel. Panel can have it's background color set to transparent if needed.

Comment: @Alex A Panel can be avoided, but that require to calculate a delta offset for the stored image to compensate for titlebar height and border-width. I didn't look into that for this example, but it's fully do-able in case the Panel causes problems in other parts of the program.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Once again, thank you. I've updated the original question with the complete code listing and a download link to the solution so you can see what I'm experiencing. Notice how when `RegionForm` inherits `Form` you can draw the rectangle on the Form however, inherit from `LayeredWindow` and nothing draws to the screen. I really want to solve this issue and hope you can continue to help me thanks!

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware I had to give you the bounty for your superb effort but I still need more help.

Comment: Alex, the LayeredWindow is a kind of bad approach for a fully transparent window so that you can draw a selection rectangle from the screen. You should search for a different solution for "Capture screen by user selection".

Comment: @Alex Sorry for delay (long week-end). I agree with Matthias. The better approach is to grab the screen and then paint it to a normal (borderless) window and do the selection on top of that. This way you are also sure that what is selected from is the what the user actually is getting as there can be changes in the mean time on the main screen and you eliminate all the current problems.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware As far as a design perspective, I agree that is much more effective and easier! However, it does not give the desired effect I would like for this application. I was perfectly content with the code's performance (see it in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdw2a4-vVTo) until I tried it on my brother's computer and it was choppy. I tried a similar tool called Gyazo on the same system and it is much, much smoother. Although evident ally difficult, it must be possible! Are you experienced with LayeredWindows? I know it's a very un documented topic from experience.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Does this mean you cannot help any further? I am making the transition from WinForms to WPF a the moment so will mostly likely resolve my issues using WPF. But regardless, I don't like to leave a conundrum unsolved.

Comment: @Alex I cannot see from the YT demo what they are doing. It's possible some DirectX is involved (WPF's using this at the bottom too, so that will bring you closer). With GDI+ you will need to capture the screen at first as it work-pipe is pretty static (not suitable for high-performing/"live" graphics), layered windows won't help much in that regard as you add a layer of complexity too (emulated alpha). I am afraid I'm unable to "squeeze" more out of it than this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok Alex, here to code example you requested.

First, you have to set some styles onto the control which you paint yourself. This is DoubleBuffered, AllPaintingInWmPaint and UserPaint. This avoids flickering (see [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12870/Don-t-Flicker-Double-Buffer)). Second, don't paint in the MouseMove event itself. Remember all data that you need for painting and call Invalidate. Do all painting in override method "Control.OnPaint" or event "Cotrol.Paint". I also added a KeyPress handler, so that I can close your RegionForm again.

On MouseDown event I remember the location of the mouse cursor and the current look (bitmap) of the control. While MouseMove I calculate the vector (distance) between the mouse down location and the current mouse cursor position. This also works if the user goes to the upper left side of the mouse down point. This rectangle is the new region that has to be drawn. But we also have to invalidate the old region. This is why I caluclate a union rectangle which contains both, the old and the new region. This union is used for calling "Control.Invalidate". Clearing the old region is simply done by drawing only the specific part of the saved image.

```
public sealed partial class RegionForm : Form
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private bool mouseDown;
    private Rectangle newRegion;
    private Rectangle oldRegion;
    private Point startPoint;

    public RegionForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;
        Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        TopMost = true;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;

        this.SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
            this.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        bitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width,
                    this.ClientSize.Height,
                    PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
        startPoint = e.Location;
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);

        mouseDown = false;

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmap = null;
        }

        // reset regions
        newRegion = Rectangle.Empty;
        oldRegion = Rectangle.Empty;

        // invalidate all
        Invalidate(true);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (mouseDown)
        {
            // calculate new region
            var vector = Point.Subtract(e.Location, new Size(startPoint));
            newRegion = new Rectangle(System.Math.Min(startPoint.X, e.Location.X), System.Math.Min(startPoint.Y, e.Location.Y), System.Math.Abs(vector.X), System.Math.Abs(vector.Y));

            // invalidate only the area of interest
            var invalidate = Rectangle.Union(oldRegion, newRegion);
            Invalidate(invalidate, true);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;

        ClearRegion(e.Graphics, bitmap, oldRegion);
        DrawRegion(e.Graphics, newRegion);

        // remember which region has been handled
        oldRegion = newRegion;
    }

    static void DrawRegion(Graphics g, Rectangle region)
    {
        if (g == null || region == Rectangle.Empty)
            return;

        //Draw a red rectangle
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, region);
    }

    static void ClearRegion(Graphics g, Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle region)
    {
        if (g == null || region == Rectangle.Empty || bitmap == null)
            return;

        // take only the selected region from the original image and draw that part
        g.DrawImage(bitmap, region, region, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
```

Comment: Solution for VisualStudio .NET 2012 can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtd9uvz049vzogg/RegionDrag.zip).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response @Matthias! With a plain windows forms application, this code gives the same speed as the first code sample I posted before the update. However the issue never lied with a plain windows forms application but with the `LayeredWindow` I can't test this code with layered windows because the class I mustered together from various sources online doesn't support the Invalidate overloads that this code needs. I am hoping you could look at `LayeredWindow.cs` and see if you can get the layered window working with the code you provided as I cannot! I'm really stuck!

Comment: Ok. I will look at it tomorrow. You should have mentioned this before sending the link. Because in the current solution the layeredwindow is inactive and it took me about an hour to assemble the new solution.

Comment: Sorry, I should of documented it more in the solution. Another big thank you to you and I look forward to hearing back from you tomorrow.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that's a hell of ... If I derive RegionDrag from LayeredWindow (in your solution) the invalidate method of the LayeredWindow will actually never be called. The PaintNative method just presents a bitmap onto the screen. But it always takes the full size of the control and is therefore slow. I derived from LayeredWindow in my solution and changed all painting methods so that only the area that has changed is drawn. Also the mousedown and mousemove locations must be absolute on screen now. The CPU usage is okay, as long as the selection (red rectangle) is small. Can help you more.

Comment: download new solution [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39b0y0t2wsx011l/RegionDragLayered.zip) The topic is quite complex and I don't have more time to spend on it. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This highly depends on the content that is visible on the form. For example, if you are drawing lots of own objects by yourself, you need to invalidate the complete form on every mouse-move event.

Otherwise you need to invalidate a specific region only. Then you need to clear that region with a background color and call all objects that are fully or partly located in that region to re-draw themselves. Afterwards you can draw your DragDrop cursor/graphic.

Mostly it is too complicated to determine the objects that are in the invalidated region.

Comment: Can you send me the VisualStudio solution of your example? I can work on that then.

Comment: See all changes in the new answer above.