# How to properly clear or update a drawn rectangle on the screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, gdi+, rectangles

I'm using a semi-transparent Form to capture the mouse events such as **LeftButtonDown**, **LeftButtonUp** and **MouseMove** to be able to select an area on the screen to draw a rectangle on that area, the problem is that a new rectangle is drawn every time that I move the mouse producing an annoying result like this:

[image]

I just would like to update the drawn rectangle when I move the mouse to the new mouse location to expect a result like this else:

[image]

I've tried to dispose, clear, and re-instance the `Graphics` object without luck, also I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682543/drawing-and-clearing-on-screen-with-graphics-fromhwnd) S.O. question that talks about this.

This is the relevant part of the code that I'm using:

```
''' <summary>
''' The Graphics object to draw on the screen.
''' </summary>
Dim ScreenGraphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)

Private Sub MouseEvents_MouseMove(ByVal MouseLocation As Point) Handles MouseEvents.MouseMove

    ' If left mouse button is hold then set the rectangle area...
    If IsMouseLeftDown Then

        ' ... blah blah blah
        ' ... more code here

        ' Draw the rectangle area.
        Me.DrawRectangle()

    End If

''' <summary>
''' Draws the rectangle on the selected area.
''' </summary>
Private Sub DrawRectangle()

    ' Call the "EraseRectanglehere" method here before re-drawing ?
    ' Me.EraseRectangle

    Using pen As New Pen(Me.BorderColor, Me.BorderSize)
        ScreenGraphic.DrawRectangle(pen, SelectionRectangle)
    End Using

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Erases the last drawn rectangle.
''' </summary>
Private Sub EraseRectangle()

End Sub
```

And here is the full code if someone need to inspectionate it better:

> NOTE: I've updated the code that I'm using now in my last question edit.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class RangeSelector : Inherits Form

#Region " Properties "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the border size of the range selector.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The size of the border.</value>
    Public Property BorderSize As Integer = 2

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the border color of the range selector.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The color of the border.</value>
    Public Property BorderColor As Color = Color.Red

#End Region

#Region " Objects "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the initial location when the mouse left button is clicked.
    ''' </summary>
    Private InitialLocation As Point = Point.Empty

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the rectangle that contains the selected area.
    ''' </summary>
    Private SelectionRectangle As Rectangle = Rectangle.Empty

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The Graphics object to draw on the screen.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ScreenGraphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RangeSelector"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RangeSelector" /> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="BorderSize">Indicates the border size of the range selector.</param>
    ''' <param name="BorderColor">Indicates the border color of the range selector.</param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal BorderSize As Integer, ByVal BorderColor As Color)

        Me.BorderSize = BorderSize
        Me.BorderColor = BorderColor

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Event Handlers "

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)

        ' MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
        InitialLocation = e.Location
        SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(InitialLocation.X, InitialLocation.Y, 0, 0)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(e As MouseEventArgs)

        ' Make the Form transparent to take the region screenshot.
        Me.Opacity = 0.0R

        ' ToDo:
        ' take the screenshot.
        ' Return the selected rectangle area and save it.

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)

        ' If left mouse button is hold then set the rectangle area...
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then

            If (e.Location.X < Me.InitialLocation.X) _
            AndAlso (e.Location.Y < Me.InitialLocation.Y) Then ' Top-Left

                Me.SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(e.Location.X,
                                                      e.Location.Y,
                                                      Me.InitialLocation.X - e.Location.X,
                                                      Me.InitialLocation.Y - e.Location.Y)

            ElseIf (e.Location.X > Me.InitialLocation.X) _
            AndAlso (e.Location.Y < Me.InitialLocation.Y) Then ' Top-Right

                Me.SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(Me.InitialLocation.X,
                                                      e.Location.Y,
                                                      e.Location.X - Me.InitialLocation.X,
                                                      Me.InitialLocation.Y - e.Location.Y)

            ElseIf (e.Location.X < Me.InitialLocation.X) _
            AndAlso (e.Location.Y > Me.InitialLocation.Y) Then ' Bottom-Left

                Me.SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(e.Location.X,
                                                      Me.InitialLocation.Y,
                                                      Me.InitialLocation.X - e.Location.X,
                                                      e.Location.Y - Me.InitialLocation.Y)

            ElseIf (e.Location.X > Me.InitialLocation.X) _
            AndAlso (e.Location.Y > Me.InitialLocation.Y) Then ' Bottom-Right

                Me.SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(Me.InitialLocation.X,
                                                      Me.InitialLocation.Y,
                                                      e.Location.X - Me.InitialLocation.X,
                                                      e.Location.Y - Me.InitialLocation.Y)
            End If

            ' Draw the rectangle area.
            Me.DrawRectangle()

        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()

        Me.SuspendLayout()
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None
        Me.CausesValidation = False
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
        Me.ControlBox = False
        Me.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.MinimizeBox = False
        Me.Name = "RangeSelector"
        Me.Opacity = 0.01R
        Me.ShowIcon = False
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide
        Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Draws the rectangle on the selected area.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub DrawRectangle()

        ' Just a weird trick to refresh the painting.
        ' Me.Opacity = 0.0R
        ' Me.Opacity = 0.01R

        ' Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)

        Using pen As New Pen(Me.BorderColor, Me.BorderSize)
            ScreenGraphic.DrawRectangle(pen, Me.SelectionRectangle)
        End Using

        ' End Using

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

> UPDATE 1

I've translated all the code to use it as a `Form` dialog to have more flexibility when selecting a region, I've replaced the entire code above to update my question, the code does not change too much just instead using a LL Hook to capture the mouse events I'm handling the mouse events of a semi-transparent maximized Form, I still drawing the rectangle on the **Desktop Screen Graphics** (not on the `OnPaint` Form event) that part of the code is the same as you can see in the code above:

```
Private ScreenGraphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)
```

...'cause as I've said the Form is semi-transparent so if I draw a rectangle in the Form it will be semi-transparent too (or at least I don't know a way to avoid that).

Then I've discover a weird trick to solve the rectangle issue by changing the opacity of the Form before drawing the rectangle in the new coordinates:

```
    Me.Opacity = 0.0R
    Me.Opacity = 0.01R

    Using pen As New Pen(Me.BorderColor, Me.BorderSize)
        ScreenGraphic.DrawRectangle(pen, Me.SelectionRectangle)
    End Using
```

The problem? ...Is not perfect, it generates a very annoying effect 'cause I get a lot of flickering when drawing the rectangle (and yes I have the Form doubleBuffered and also I'm using the `CreateParams` trick to try to avoid flickering, but nothing).

> UPDATE 2

I've tried to use what @**Plutonix** pointed in his comment, the [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, with this API declaration:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function InvalidateRect(
        ByVal hWnd As Integer,
        ByRef lpRect As Rectangle,
        ByVal bErase As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function
```

I've tried to use it with both `False`/`True` Flags.

The problem? the problem is the same as the one that I pointed in my first update:

'Is not perfect, it generates a very annoying effect 'cause I get a lot of flickering when drawing the rectangle (and yes I have the Form doubleBuffered and also I'm using the `CreateParams` trick to try to avoid flickering, but nothing).'

> UPDATE 3

I'm trying to fix this issue using the [RedrawWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which as I've seen in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325894/difference-between-invalidaterect-and-redrawwindow) it can be used to do the same as [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function does but also with more flexibility and maybe without the annoying effect that I get using the [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, I just needed to try it.

> The RedrawWindow function updates the specified rectangle or region in
>   a window's client area.

This is the API declaration:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function RedrawWindow(
        ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,
        <[In]> ByRef lprcUpdate As Rectangle,
        ByVal hrgnUpdate As IntPtr,
        ByVal flags As RedrawWindowFlags) As Boolean
End Function

<Flags()>
Private Enum RedrawWindowFlags As UInteger
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Invalidates the rectangle or region that you specify in lprcUpdate or hrgnUpdate.
    ''' You can set only one of these parameters to a non-NULL value. If both are NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE invalidates the entire window.
    ''' </summary>
    Invalidate = &H1

    ''' <summary>Causes the OS to post a WM_PAINT message to the window regardless of whether a portion of the window is invalid.</summary>
    InternalPaint = &H2

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Causes the window to receive a WM_ERASEBKGND message when the window is repainted.
    ''' Specify this value in combination with the RDW_INVALIDATE value; otherwise, RDW_ERASE has no effect.
    ''' </summary>
    [Erase] = &H4

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Validates the rectangle or region that you specify in lprcUpdate or hrgnUpdate.
    ''' You can set only one of these parameters to a non-NULL value. If both are NULL, RDW_VALIDATE validates the entire window.
    ''' This value does not affect internal WM_PAINT messages.
    ''' </summary>
    Validate = &H8

    NoInternalPaint = &H10

    ''' <summary>Suppresses any pending WM_ERASEBKGND messages.</summary>
    NoErase = &H20

    ''' <summary>Excludes child windows, if any, from the repainting operation.</summary>
    NoChildren = &H40

    ''' <summary>Includes child windows, if any, in the repainting operation.</summary>
    AllChildren = &H80

    ''' <summary>Causes the affected windows, which you specify by setting the RDW_ALLCHILDREN and RDW_NOCHILDREN values, to receive WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT messages before the RedrawWindow returns, if necessary.</summary>
    UpdateNow = &H100

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Causes the affected windows, which you specify by setting the RDW_ALLCHILDREN and RDW_NOCHILDREN values, to receive WM_ERASEBKGND messages before RedrawWindow returns, if necessary.
    ''' The affected windows receive WM_PAINT messages at the ordinary time.
    ''' </summary>
    EraseNow = &H200

    Frame = &H400

    NoFrame = &H800
End Enum
```

I've tried to use the function with these parameters:

```
RedrawWindow(IntPtr.Zero, Me.SelectionRectangle, IntPtr.Zero, RedrawWindowFlags.Invalidate)
```

...Which I suppose that as the MSDN documentation describes, if the first parameter is NULL it means the desktop screen, the second parameter means the rectangle to update, the third parameter need to be null if I've specified a rectangle in the second parameter, and the last parameter means a flag that indicates the action(s) to perform (in this case invalidate the rectangle as @**Plutonix** said?)

I've tried to use that isntruction after drawing the rectangle and before drawing it, I mean in the `OnMouseMove` event, and else inside my `DrawRectangle` method in my code, but I don't see any difference in the screen, I still have the same problem that I shown in the images above when drawing the rectangle I mean that multiple rectangles are drawn when I move the mouse and any rectangle is erased by this function, maybe I'm using the wrong parameters?.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361234/gdi-drawing-rectangle-is-slow/13438008#13438008

Comment: @Epistemex thankyou for your comment but really I don't understand the 'ClearRegion' method posted there and I need to use an online converter from C# to VB.NET. anyways I'm gonna try it, thanks again.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the answer, there's full VB source

Comment: @ElektroStudios https://www.google.no/search?q=csharp+to+vb

Comment: @Epistemex, sorry my fault, what a dismissal.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå thanks but I didn't expressed properly my words, I mean that even using an online code translator I need to understand the code (what it does). like I've said I'm gonna try it before still saying things and dismissals that maybe could be obvious once I've read all the code. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do you have a reproducing example?

Comment: In general, I think what you need to do is to invalidate the current selection rect before you update it when the mouse moves (InvalidateRect). The trick is whom to send the message to, since there could be several windows in the rect.  Would it work to find the visible window under the cursor and draw a line 1px inside the frame? If they move elsewhere, the native paint proc would erase your rect.  Snag-It does this.

Comment: @Plutonix thankyou for your help, please could you see my three updates of my question to point me in the right direction?, I've used the invalidateRect function and also the RedrawWindow function without luck.

Comment: I've updated the full source code of the rectangle selector (which is a very tiny code) for people who maybe want to try it to see what happens, only need to copy the code and run it like this only in one line: `Using Selector As New RangeSelector : Selector.ShowDialog() : End Using`

Comment: Ok, this works pretty smoothly: use 2 forms.  Form1 is maximized, no controlbox, no taskbar and displays a bitmap of the screen.  Form2 acts as as the  SelectionRect: BackColor WhiteSmoke, Opacity 25% (looks like the Win select rect effect). In the mouse events on Form1, set the location/size of frmRect.  By not actually drawing rects, Windows erases/repaints things nicely **for you** (though I do not have it coded to work 'upside down').  Capture the section represented by frmR.Bounds on mouseup.  You could also let them drag and resize the form instead of accounting for upside dn.

Comment: @Plutonix `and displays a bitmap of the screen` you mean to "take an screenshot/image" of the actual screen and use that image as the BackgroundImage property of the Form1 ?. In that case I can't 'cause my intentions is to not "freeze" the screen in any way but if I take an image of the screen to select an area of that image I'm freezing "the screen", I just need to found the way to clean properly the drawn rects on the screen. thanks for yout help

Comment: How much can be going on back there if your app/selector is active?  If you draw rects to the desktop/screen they are now on a canvas you dont own/have access to. Windows/Explorer did not draw them so it cant be expected to know how to erase them.  My 2 forms trick allows you to draw/erase a canvas you own.  Try using Form1 as a maximized transparent form (canvas) with the other form acting as the selection rect (set frmRect size/location from frmTrans) mouseevents.  Since frmRect is a control, windows erases it nicely.  Some of the painting still ends up on the desktop briefly, but it works.

Comment: Yet another way would be to go all API: find the window the mouse is over, get its rect, maybe flash the window to signal what will be captured, then get the image from that location.  The problem is selecting a window which is overlapped.

Comment: check the updates at the bottom of my post. i can't find a way to do it without hooking to the mouse. well, i found a 'hack', about to try putting it on a timer, but the downside is you have a square below the cursor, so you continue to receive messages for the window. oh actually, zero beat me to it... lol. there's still some useful info in the post. and yea, you will probably have to hook the mouse from the look of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is more simple and windows API isn't required. Just create a transparent from and draw red rectangle on it. Following code do that, you only need to replace in your semi transparent form. The flickering happens because we clean the graphics and then draw, the easiest way to avoid it is do painting at once, so if we paint the rectangle on a bitmap and then draw the bitmap, operation is done in one step and flickering doesn't happens.

Drawing will be done on OnPaintBackground of the drawing form so a drawing form with will be needed. This is the main class, where the events are captured:

```
Public Class YourFormClass

    Dim Start As Point
    Dim DrawSize As Size
    Public DrawRect As Rectangle
    Public Drawing As Boolean = False
    Dim Info As Label
    Dim DrawForm As Form

    Private Sub YourFormClass_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ControlBox = False
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        BackColor = Color.Gray
        Opacity = 0.2

        DrawForm = New DrawingFormClass(Me)
        With DrawForm
            .BackColor = Color.Tomato
            .TopLevel = True
            .TransparencyKey = Color.Tomato
            .TopMost = True
            .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
            .ControlBox = False
            .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        End With

        Info = New Label
        With Info
            .Top = 16
            .Left = 16
            .ForeColor = Color.White
            .AutoSize = True
            DrawForm.Controls.Add(Info)
        End With

        Me.AddOwnedForm(DrawForm)
        DrawForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        Drawing = True
        Start = e.Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        If Drawing Then
            DrawSize = New Size(e.X - Start.X, e.Y - Start.Y)
            DrawRect = New Rectangle(Start, DrawSize)

            If DrawRect.Height < 0 Then
                DrawRect.Height = Math.Abs(DrawRect.Height)
                DrawRect.Y -= DrawRect.Height
            End If

            If DrawRect.Width < 0 Then
                DrawRect.Width = Math.Abs(DrawRect.Width)
                DrawRect.X -= DrawRect.Width
            End If

            Info.Text = DrawRect.ToString
            DrawForm.Invalidate()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        Drawing = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

As drawing will be done in OnPaintBackground, a second class is needed:

```
Public Class DrawingFormClass

    Private DrawParent As YourFormClass

    Public Sub New(Parent As YourFormClass)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.DrawParent = YourFormClass
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim Bg As Bitmap
        Dim Canvas As Graphics


        If DrawParent.Drawing Then
            Bg = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
            Canvas = Graphics.FromImage(Bg)
            Canvas.Clear(Color.Tomato)
            Canvas.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, DrawParent.DrawRect)
            Canvas.Dispose()
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bg, 0, 0, Width, Height)

            Bg.Dispose()
        Else
            MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Just create two forms and paste... It will create the drawing form and draw the red rectangle creating a bitmap buffer so only one operation is done when drawing. This works very fine without flickering. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thankyou but I've tried it and it just shows a TopMost transparent form, but I'm unable to "draw" anything, when I press left click it does nothing. I'm missing something?

Comment: I guessed some properties of main form... I've edited and added required properties and now it works, could you try it please?

Comment: yes now it works in my side, it's amazing, well your Form still has flickering when the rectangle is redrawn all the time but at least is much less flickering than my starting approach, thankyou.

Comment: I've tried to set the 'DoubleBuffered' property of the 'DrawForm' without success it says it's protected, could you extend your solution in a way to avoid the flickering of the rectangle? i will appreciate it, thanks

Comment: Sure! edited and Updated... now does the same without flickering. Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry but again the Form is displayed but when I click on it it does not draw anything, you've missed a property this time or something? thanks

Comment: Hi! I've tested creating a new project and it works: create an emtpy project. In main form (launching form) copy/paste first part of code (YourFormClass), then create a second form and paste second part of code (DrawingFormClass) and run. I guess you probably are launching or instantiating from DrawingFormClass that is the secondary form.

Comment: It works, the problem is that seems that I'm unable to use "ShowDialog" method with the form (I only can use "Show" method), so how I can expect a result properly?... this is really giving me a very headaches

Comment: joder, he visto que eres Español, a ver si me puedes echar una última mano pa esto, yo necesito "cargar" el form y esperar al evento "OnMouseUp" (que es donde yo cerraba el form al usar "ShowDialog", pero con tu form no puedo) y así proseguir con la ejecución de las demás isntrucciones, es decir, lo mismo que usar un "ShowDialog" y luego seguir con las isntrucciones que hayan debajo, ¿Me entiendes?.

Comment: Here you can see my new question if you could help me, thankyou. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008016/showdialog-method-is-not-working-properly-when-setting-the-form-parent

Answer (score 4):

Keith's answer is mostly correct, but lacking one key point:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e as PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    If bClickHolding Then e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen:=Pen, rect:=Rect)
End Sub
```

You should do your drawing in the paint event, not the event handler.

This is why you're getting flickering, because the form paint event is being drawn in between the frames, causing the buffer to be cleared.

also, here's some additional 'hacks':

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e as PaintEventArgs)
    Return ' will skip painting the background
    MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
End Sub

SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
```

you should probably draw it in a panel though. oh and don't put program logic in the OnPaint event, put it either in the handler, or in a separate thread.

if you want to draw it from another control/class, don't. instead, draw it in the main control's OnPaint event, and simply reference the object/boolean/size,location in the other control. (ie: If myBoundingbox.bClickHolding Then...)

some links that explain the issue (quote from MSDN):

> When creating a new custom control or an inherited control with a
>   different visual appearance, you must provide code to render the
>   control by overriding the OnPaint method.

[MSDN - Control.Paint Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[MSDN - Control.OnPaint Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[MSDN - Custom Control Painting and Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

hmm, after reading that part about transparency, i was going to suggest: (just set .TransparencyKey = Color.Black) but, that bypasses mouse events, would need some WndProc possibly to fix that: [MSDN - Form.TransparencyKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - hmm yea, the problem with that is the window loses focus.

possibly something like this: [MSDN - NativeWindow Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) - but probably you will need to use a mouse hook, since you're not receiving messages for the window any longer with transparency.

also, this here is a sort of 'hack', that paint a rectangle in the background behind the cursor. the problem is, the effect lags behind the cursor, so it doesn't work if you move the mouse really fast. or maybe it would be better to put it on a timer instead. i'll leave it here for now. you can use either the OnMouseMove override or the WndProc method, but i can't see a performance difference. (edit: and nope, timer doesn't reduce the lag).

```
Private Shared mouseNotify() As Int32 = {&H200, &H201, &H204, &H207} ' WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, WM_MBUTTONDOWN

Friend Shared Function isOverControl(ByRef theControl As Control) As Boolean
    Return theControl.ClientRectangle.Contains(theControl.PointToClient(Cursor.Position))
End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        'Invalidate()
        MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
        Dim x As Integer = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X - 5
        Dim y As Integer = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y - 5
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Brushes.Aqua, 1), 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 1)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, x, y, 10, 10)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If mouseNotify.Contains(CInt(m.Msg)) Then
            If isOverControl(Me) Then Invalidate()
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, yes, much smoother. My bad. Thank you. Updated my post as that's a better/correct way.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps you.

---

Update 1: Reworked the code. Handles backwards selection rectangles, less checks, etc. Cleaned it up.

Update 2: Updated to reflect porkchop's correction.

---

```
Public Class SelectionRectTesting

    Private pCurrent As Point
    Private pStart As Point
    Private pStop As Point

    Private Rect As Rectangle
    Private Graphics As Graphics
    Private Pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)

    Private bClickHolding = False

    Private Sub SelectionRectTestingLoad(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleMouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
        bClickHolding = True
        pStart.X = e.X
        pStart.Y = e.Y
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleMouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
        If bClickHolding = True Then
            pCurrent.X = e.X
            pCurrent.Y = e.Y

            If pCurrent.X < pStart.X Then
                Rect.X = pCurrent.X
                Rect.Width = pStart.X - pCurrent.X
            Else
                Rect.X = pStart.X
                Rect.Width = pCurrent.X - pStart.X
            End If

            If pCurrent.Y < pStart.Y Then
                Rect.Y = pCurrent.Y
                Rect.Height = pStart.Y - pCurrent.Y
            Else
                Rect.Y = pStart.Y
                Rect.Height = pCurrent.Y - pStart.Y
            End If

            Invalidate()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleMouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
        bClickHolding = False
        Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        If bClickHolding Then
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen:=Pen, rect:=Rect)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Return ' will skip painting the background
        MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but your code can't help me in any of the ways, the code is basically the same that I've posted in my question but you are drawing inside the Form. I don't pretend to offend you but did you read my question and the problem that I have?. I really don't understand why you've realized that code, but thanks anyways

Comment: I apologize if I misread. I read it yesterday and made a note to code it today, then read two more times after your reply to me, heh. I thought the goal was to properly draw a selection rectangle a single time and have it update as you move the mouse with the button held down, leaving no previously drawn rectangles behind. The code I posted does exactly that. Sorry once again if I misunderstood.

Comment: yes, that's exactlly what I wanted but OUTSIDE the Form as I've clarified in my question I'm trying to draw the rectangles over the screen not inside a Form, the reason is I didn't found a way to do this using a transparent Form then I'm drawing the rectangles in the screen, but thankyou again for help!

Comment: Keith really your code runs very well and without ay kind of annoying effects, but understand that this is not what I was looking for, unless that you could find the way to adapt it to my needs as @ZeroWorks similar code it's, sorry for my English, what I mean is that I need to select an area of the screen, then using an opaque Form I think it can't help me, and using a transparent form I'm unable to draw a visible rectangle inside that Form 'cause the transparency, but maybe I'm wrong and it can be do it that way.